# Can I compare fields from another line in the same table

Tags: oracle, compare, cumulative-sum

I have a table where the quantity of the line is generated increasingly per Order.
So instead of having Qty per box I have :

- Qty Box 2 = Qty Box1+Qty Box2
- Qty Box 3 = Qty Box2+Qty Box3,  etc...

I found a way to calculate Qty per box in Excel with this formula:

```
= IF(Line2(Order)=Line1(Order) THEN (Line2(Qty)-Line1(Qty) ELSE Line2(Qty)
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to do this in Oracle.

Current Table:

```
SELECT ORDER, BOX, QTY
FROM TABLE

     ORDER        BOX        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
     12345       4501         50
     12345       4502        100
     12345       4503        150
     12345       4504        200
     12345       4505        250
     12354       5401         40
     12354       5402        100
     12354       5403        160
     12354       5404        220
     12360       6001         20
     12360       6002         42
     12360       6003         62
```

Expected Result:

```
     ORDER        BOX        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
     12345       4501         50
     12345       4502         50
     12345       4503         50
     12345       4504         50
     12345       4505         50
     12354       5401         40
     12354       5402         60
     12354       5403         60
     12354       5404         60
     12360       6001         20
     12360       6002         22
     12360       6003         20
```

Comment: Fields Order & Box are Varchar, Field Qty is Numeric. The boxes are linked to a Specific Order.

Comment: Is this a school exercise or an IRL problem? I would be very concerned about a data model which persisted a running total across records.

Answer (score 2):

Use an analytic LAG() function.

```
select order_no
       , box_no
       , qty
       , nvl(qty-lag(qty) over (partition by order_no order by box), qty) as box_qty
from orders
order by 1 , 2
/
```

This assumes `(order_no, box)` is your unique key, and that `box` is assigned is a rising series within `order_no`. If your actual rules are different you will need to revise the window clause.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need `lag()` function, which looks into previous row:

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd75ceab8a7b5e1d7fe3837d598f18b0)</sup>**

```
select order_, box, qty, 
       qty - nvl(lag(qty) over (partition by order_ order by box), 0) 
  from tbl
```